# How can I convert a @startuml code into a GraphML?

Tags: uml, plantuml, graphml

I have created a @startuml code that generates some class and sequence diagrams using PlantUML and it looks good but I would like to be able to edit the resulting graph using GraphML with the yed-live tool from yworks.com for example.

How can I convert the @startuml code to be compatible with GraphML?

Example:

```
@startuml

Bob -> Alice: Hello!

@enduml
```

And you can check the result in https://www.planttext.com/

Comment: how ? just implementing your own translator ... but what is the interest ? If you want to edit using GraphML use GraphML from the beginning. These tools do not have the same goal/philosophy. However if you want to do UML (which is not only diagrams) use a UML modeler, none of these tools are UML tool even they have some notation from UML. GraphML is a generic drawing tool for graph, and PlantUML even its name does not follow UML standard to draw elements in a lot of cases.

Comment: Hi @bruno, thanks for your answer, I have a lot of big PlantUML diagrams like class diagrams and sequence diagrams.

Comment: Hi, I was afraid of that, now you have to consider how long to reenter all manually in GraphML  and how long to implement the translator. I am also afraid to move to GraphML  will be a problem later as it was for PlantUML ... good luck ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the official PlantUML tool to generate UML diagrams easily.

Just copy & paste your code and it will generate it automatically as in my example.

UML generating demo:

[image: UML generating demo]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but I am temporarily out of the project, so it will take some time before I can test your solution.

Comment: Thanks @abdelhadi-hireche for your comment, but that's what I already have. I have the diagrams in PlantUML and I need to move them to GraphML.